# Dentro de un procedimiento almacenado ¿Cómo añadir una variable en una consulta utilizado like adjuntando 3 tablas con join en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join

> ```
> create procedure select 
> @dato int 
> as
> begin
> select C.nombre as Cliente, A.nombre as Asociacion,M.fechaIncorporacion as 
> FechaIncorporacion,  M.estatusMiembro as Estatus
> from Miembros M inner join Asociaciones A on A.idAsosiacion M.idAsosiacion 
> inner join Clientes C on C.idCliente = M.idCliente
> where M.idAsosiacion like @dato+'%'  or M.idCliente like @dato+'%'
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

el problema lo tienes al intentar llamar al procedimiento "SELECT" que es una palabra reservada. Cambia el nombre y en teoría debería funcionar.

Me cuentas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure [P_select]
@dato int 
as
begin
select C.nombre as Cliente, A.nombre as Asociacion,M.fechaIncorporacion as 
FechaIncorporacion,  M.estatusMiembro as Estatus
from Miembros M 
inner join Asociaciones A on A.idAsosiacion M.idAsosiacion 
inner join Clientes C on C.idCliente = M.idCliente
where M.idAsosiacion like CONCAT(@dato+'%')  or M.idCliente like CONCAT(@dato+'%')
```

otra problema que identifique es el tipo de datos en like, por eso le agrege la funcion concat que debe ayudarte, porque se realizara una conversion implicita, ten cuidado con los tipos de dato.